# Can I conditionally add numbers to certain repeated values in a column in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset that i wish to align and make a tree with. I have a data frame with two columns, species and nucleotides. Where species level hasn't been found it is filled with the next available taxonomic level up (i.e. genus, family, order, etc.). This, however, means that there is a single name representing multiple species and sequences. There is also replicated species level rows.
I would like to put a number (or something to make it a unique name) after the replicated genus/family/order name and to remove the duplicated species names.

```
species <- c("Anthophore plumipes", "Anthophore plumipes", "Ormosia hederae", "Tipula varipennis", "Tipula varipennis", "Tipula", "Tipula", "Lepidoptera", "Lepidoptera", "Lepidoptera")

nucleotides <- c("ACTGGTTGAACGGTTTAT", "ACTGGTTGAACGGTTTAT", "AACATTATATTTTATTTTT", "CACATTATATTTTATTTTT", "CACATTATATTTTATTTTT", "AACATTATATTTTATTTTT", "GACATTATATTTTATTTTT", "TACATTATATTTTATTTTT", "AACTCTTTATTTTATTTTT", "CTCATTATATTTTATTTTT")

df <- data.frame(species, nucleotides)

> df
               species         nucleotides
1  Anthophore plumipes  ACTGGTTGAACGGTTTAT
2  Anthophore plumipes  ACTGGTTGAACGGTTTAT
3      Ormosia hederae AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
4    Tipula varipennis CACATTATATTTTATTTTT
5    Tipula varipennis CACATTATATTTTATTTTT
6               Tipula AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
7               Tipula GACATTATATTTTATTTTT
8          Lepidoptera TACATTATATTTTATTTTT
9          Lepidoptera AACTCTTTATTTTATTTTT
10         Lepidoptera CTCATTATATTTTATTTTT
```

I want the output to look like:

```
> df
               species         nucleotides
1  Anthophore plumipes  ACTGGTTGAACGGTTTAT
2      Ormosia hederae AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
3    Tipula varipennis CACATTATATTTTATTTTT
4              Tipula1 AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
5              Tipula2 GACATTATATTTTATTTTT
6         Lepidoptera1 TACATTATATTTTATTTTT
7         Lepidoptera2 AACTCTTTATTTTATTTTT
8         Lepidoptera3 CTCATTATATTTTATTTTT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(!duplicated(paste(species,nucleotides))) %>% group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(species=paste0(species,1:n()))

# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   species [8]
  species              nucleotides        
  <chr>                <chr>              
1 Anthophore plumipes1 ACTGGTTGAACGGTTTAT 
2 Ormosia hederae1     AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
3 Tipula varipennis1   CACATTATATTTTATTTTT
4 Tipula1              AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
5 Tipula2              GACATTATATTTTATTTTT
6 Lepidoptera1         TACATTATATTTTATTTTT
7 Lepidoptera2         AACTCTTTATTTTATTTTT
8 Lepidoptera3         CTCATTATATTTTATTTTT
```

Comment: you could use `distinct(species, nucleotides)` instead of the `filter` statement too

Answer (score 0):

This would work too, using dplyr and purrr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  distinct(species, nucleotides) %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  mutate(n_spp = n()) %>%
  split(.$species) %>%
  map(function(sp.x) {
    n_vec <- ifelse(sp.x$n_spp == 1, "", 1:nrow(sp.x))
    sp.x$species <- paste0(sp.x$species, n_vec)
    sp.x %>% select(-n_spp)
  }) %>%
  bind_rows

# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   species [8]
  species             nucleotides        
  <chr>               <chr>              
1 Anthophore plumipes ACTGGTTGAACGGTTTAT 
2 Lepidoptera1        TACATTATATTTTATTTTT
3 Lepidoptera2        AACTCTTTATTTTATTTTT
4 Lepidoptera3        CTCATTATATTTTATTTTT
5 Ormosia hederae     AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
6 Tipula1             AACATTATATTTTATTTTT
7 Tipula2             GACATTATATTTTATTTTT
8 Tipula varipennis   CACATTATATTTTATTTTT
```